# Why strings are not being added to array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I need to find all of the elements with the class `.selected` in my DOM, extract the text of that element and add the text string to an array.  I have the following code, but the only thing that is being logged in the console is an integer number.  How can I reach my original goal?

```
openOrderBox: function() {
        var servicesArray = []
        $( ".selected" ).each(function() {
            var serviceName = $(this).children('#service-name').text()
            servicesArray = servicesArray.push(serviceName)
        });
        console.log(servicesArray);
},
```

Comment: `children('#service-name')` implies you're getting the children with the id 'service-name', and ids are unique so this can only ever return one element. Also `servicesArray = servicesArray.push(serviceName)` seems wrong to me, it should just just `servicesArray.push(serviceName);`.

Comment: After pushing a value into the array, you don't need to reassign to it, since the `.push` method doesn't return the resulting array, but the new length.

Comment: The return value of the `push` method is the new length of the array. So reassigning the variable means it becomes a number after the first iteration, and therefore won't have a `push` method anymore (and obviously won't be the array you expect)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't set the value of the array again, just push to it:

```
var servicesArray = [];

$( ".selected" ).each(function() {
    var serviceName = $(this).children('#service-name').text();
    servicesArray.push(serviceName);
});
```

of course, `#service-name` is an ID, and those are unique, so you'll get the same value every time, or at least you should, unless you have invalid markup ?

Comment: Even if there's multiple `#service-name` elements, it will always return the same element. A good point, nonetheless

Comment: @Ian - Actually, when using DOM traversal like children(), it won't always return the first element with that ID in the DOM, but rather the first element in the collection with that ID, so it will somewhat work, see fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/ZcFGB/ ...?

Comment: So, there's 2 problems. #1: I somehow misread that...I didn't see the `$(this).children(` part, I guess :( And #2: This http://jsfiddle.net/ZcFGB/1/ more clearly explains what I **meant**, but is wrong anyways because using `children()` negates my point. I'm guessing it's because it will use `querySelectorAll` internally, which does find all elements with that ID (unlike `getElementById`, which is used when the root selector is by `id`). If it were `$("#service-name")`, my point might have been correct :)